# Регистронезависимость имени файла и папок

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, php

Как прописать в .htaccess регистронезависимость имен файлов и папок, а точнее, чтобы было все равно .jpg или .JPG?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить ключ `[NC]`
Например, в этом случае все файлы *.png* и *.PNG* будут отображать *panda.png*

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/.*\.png$ dummy/panda.png  [NC,L]
```